# 53C94 SCSI IC as target - Cannot handle WRITE(10) command from Initiator

Tags: scsi

I am building a SD card/SCSI adapter using NCR 53CF94 IC and STM32.
All goes pretty well, even manged to make my device work to some degree, i.e. accepting all basic commands and even booting from it to DOS. BUT i have a problem, when asking initiator (PC) to write something to my device , all goes well i get the block address and the data. Then i write the data to SD card and finally responding with status=0 and message=0 to complete the write command, but the initiaor never increasing the secoor number to continue to write proccess and always tries to write the first one, then after few attempts it gives error on the PC (Error writing to drive...). I can't figure it out why the initiaor is not satisfied with the GOOD status and message. Do i need to send some specific data back to the initiator ? Linke CRC ? Or there is some specific command i need to issue for 53C94 ?
Banging my head for few days now.
Need your assistance please.

Thanks !

- Artiom.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was writing 512 byte blocks to a 256 byte array. I'm not sure how this is related to the issue, but after fixing the size everything started to work.